I want nginx to use as reverse proxy for my aspnetcore app
I have docker-compose.yaml as below. My app is deployed on linux server in a dockerized env. as below:
version: '3.8'

services:
  mejaz-sqls:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: appstationmssql
    hostname: app2stationmssql
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "abcd123"
      MSSQL_PID: Enterprise
    volumes:
      - ./sqls-data/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./sqls-data/log:/var/opt/mssql/log
      - ./sqls-data/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - applab-mejaz-nw

  mejaz-api:
    build:
      context: ./mejaz-api-latest
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    user: root
    networks:
      - applab-ejaz-nw

  redis:
    image: 'redis:7.2'
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
      - ./redis-data:/data
      - ./redis-backup:/backup 
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    environment:
      - REDIS_CONNECTION_STRING=Redis
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - applab-mejaz-nw

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: mejaz-nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/cache:/var/cache/nginx
      - /etc/ssl/ejaz-ssl:/etc/ssl/ejaz-ssl
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    networks:
      - applab-mejaz-nw



networks:
 applab-mejaz-nw:
    driver: bridge  

i have nginx.conf inside nginx folder as below:

http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    # Enable Gzip compression
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=1g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
    
    log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$upstream_cache_status"';
    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
    server_tokens  off;
    
    # Adjust keepalive_timeout to the lowest possible value that makes sense 
    # for your use case.
    keepalive_timeout   29;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    send_timeout 10;
    
    upstream helloapp {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name mejaz.app.qa;
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ejaz-ssl/ejaz-cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ejaz-ssl/ejaz-key.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-   POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling off;
    
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://mejaz.app.com/api/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache my_cache;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 302 24h;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    
            # Enable SSL certificate verification for production
            proxy_ssl_verify on;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/ejaz-ssl/ejaz-cert.pem;
    
            # Additional security headers
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        }
    
        location /api/ejaz/v1/Account/login {
            proxy_pass https://mejaz.app.com/api/ejaz/v1/Account/login;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
    
            proxy_cache off;
    
            # Enable SSL certificate verification for production
            proxy_ssl_verify on;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/ejaz-ssl/ejaz-cert.pem;
    
            # Additional security headers
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        }
    
        # Custom error pages
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }

}

As per the microsoft docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=linux-ubuntu i have added default.conf as below

server {
listen 80;
server_name mejaz.app.com;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass         http://mejaz-api:80/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}

In the browser when i check i did not get response from nginx server cache is showing kestrel.
what am i doing wrong here! I have tried various nginx conf but still response is being fed from kestrel. Is there anything which i am missing?
Any advice is appreciated.
